# What is the secret on the bell stage?

Tags: fez

There is a bell with four symbols, one on each side. The map node has a "?" signifying a secret in this level—what is it?

[image]

Comment: This seems like seeding: have you at least tried to play the game? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: No it's not, but the fun in playing puzzles is the hard they are more awesome you fell after beating him. When you are posting some Puzzle question, talk what you have done so far, not only "what is the trick"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[image: Fez bell puzzle tl;dr]

---

The [square symbols](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) on the bell's four sides are **numbers (1, 3, 6, and 10) that represent the amount of times to ring each side**. Any order should work. The bell disappears forever, replaced by an anticube.

Answer (score 3):

when you get to the city there is a room that lists those symbols in a certain order. the order of these symbols should tell you which order to ring the bell in, as well as the order of the treasure maps in your inventory.