# What is Fez's alphabet?

Tags: fez

I'm trying to translate the Fez alphabet/symbols, numbers included.

Could somebody post the deciphered alphabet and numbers please?

Comment: I would recommend sorting like symbols together, for me at least it has made the process a lot quicker.

Answer (score 90):

Here is my version of the Alphabet / Numbers / Inputs translation:

[image: Fez Alphabet]

---

[image: Fez Numbers]

---

[image: Fez Inputs]

Comment: Great work! Now if only I knew what LT, RT and A mean for PC...

Comment: LT and RT are rotate, and A is jump.

Comment: Is there a place in the game that helps you understand the code? Or is it supposed to be cracked just by looking at the symbols that appear on walls and objects?

Comment: So I'm confused about these codes. Does the game actually lead to realize/learn these codes somewhere? Or is this actually like, "Oh I think I see a pattern". And then you pull out a notebook and start fiddling around?

Comment: @lolmaus I know there is a place that tells you the symbols for keys. It’s a pillar with dots (visible in the area thumbnail). When standing near it, any time you press a button, the corresponding symbol displays and a sound plays. As for the numbers and alphabet, I’m not sure if they are ever spelled out, but one hint the game gives you is the artifacts that it tells you are “used for writing” and “used for numbers”. You can see the possible symbols by viewing and rotating the artifacts in your inventory.

Comment: @JasonD and lolmaus – [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62575/28422)’s answers point out the place where the game spells out the alphabet cipher. [This question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62763/28422)’s answers describe where the number and button ciphers are explained.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane thanks hadn't seen/noticed that. Just for the sheer terror of it, I went ahead and solved ol' substitution cipher style which took writing on actual paper, and left me with decoded messages but with some garbage. Checking my answer with these online, shows that it is indeed not a clean 1-1 substition... for anyone else that wants to try to decode it the hard way.

Answer (score 44):

PDF download: http://cl.ly/1b1F3O3D3K1T2y410G1D
[image]
(web version => lower resolution)

Comment: Note that the `e` and `z` as well as `k/q` and `x` are not the same as this image seems to imply. See the image from the other answer to see the difference.

Comment: I merged them since they were close enough to be confused. There's only [one puzzle](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62421/21177) where the E/Z difference could even matter.