# What are the Giant Telescope room's secrets?

Tags: fez

I tried pressing buttons after looking at the constellations through the telescope, but it doesn't seem to be that. I just noticed a purple square and two blinking red dots in the sky with the telescope. Is that a clue? How do I finish this room?

[image: Giant Telescope]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confirmed, however, the sequence is `R RT L RT RT A A R`.  The blinking lights also correspond to `RT` and `LT` prompts.  Just follow the lights and you get a weird red cube with a piece missing from it.

Comment: both answers are correct. they differ due to the 'start' point. if you keep entering the sequence you will eventually get it

Answer (score 10):

There are two secrets in this room.

### Constellations

Look out the telescope at night and two tetrominos constellations will show in the stars. Rotate the telescope to get a sequence of eight. [Enter the sequence](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177), looping it in case you started at the wrong point. If you want to cheat, hover for the code:

> **→ RT ← RT RT A A →**

[image: Tetromino constellations]
[image: Tetromino constellations]
[image: Tetromino constellations]
[image: Tetromino constellations]

### Red star

To "complete" the room, observe the blinking red star in the telescope:

> Turn your telescope to look in the direction of the entrance door. A blinking red star will show in the upper-left corner of the telescope's view at night. Press your left/right triggers in time with the blinking to unlock a red "heart" cube piece. The truncated code is **RT LT LT RT RT LT**. [image: Blinking red star] [image: Blinking red star]

Answer (score 0):

Answer : A Right Right RT Left RT RT A (for the first artifact)

Then do some triggering with RT (right blinking star) and LT (left blinking star) according to theirs beats !