# Where are the Heart Cubes?

Tags: fez

I have entered the 64 door room, and it shows the heart with two red cubes in it and a space for a 3rd. I cannot recall where I got the two cubes so far, and no secrets seem to be left. Where should I be looking?

Comment: one person has managed to do it, and it is one of the sound editors for the game. They probably asked the makers how to solve it or something. Anyway, they aren't telling how to do it :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the [observatory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62544/21177), in the ["What's my name" puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62421/21177), and in the [candle room](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62515/21177).**

[image: observatory cube piece]
[image: heart cube piece]
[image: monolith heart cube piece]
[image: finished heart]

Comment: i'm fairly sure i've done all these. The Whats my name puzzle took me HOURS. Ive got the obelisk in the candle room and ive done the stars happy fun time in the observatory. I'm going to double check them, but since they are gold i'm worried i'm bugged out.

Comment: Hate to double post, but I have confirmed the 2 of the heart pieces (monolith and observatory) leaving just the security code - which despite me being double sure I did, other than glitch, is the only explanation - however - been looking for it for more time than I care to mention. Not worth a new question but a hint to its location on the map would be super appreciated.

Comment: Unfinished rooms should show on your map, but try this: The observatory is northwest of the temple warp zone (with the telescope). The security code/"What's my name" is in the waterfall room's basement. The candle room/black monolith is in the first warp zone's basement.

Comment: @JamesJohnston - if they have they aren't telling how. There is a question dedicated to it: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62515