# Where does the 64-cube door lead?

Tags: fez

I just want to make sure that it isn't some kind of game ending thing inside that will make me lose my map and progress.

Comment: Just wanted to link to the question that answers actually this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63197/3-heart-cube-pieces-what-next

Answer (score 4):

**It's a single room with an empty, rotating heart atop a waterfall.** You won't lose any progress and you can leave it whenever you want.

[image: empty heart]

**What do you do with it?**

> You can collect [three heart pieces to fill it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62803/where-are-the-heart-cubes). ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z099q.png))

Comment: But we still don't know what to do after having the three heart pieces...

Comment: There's nothing to do. The heart pieces were Easter eggs.