# 3 Heart Cube Pieces: What next?

Tags: fez

We know how to obtain the three heart pieces (or red cubes, if you want), but now? What next?

It just doesn't make sense that after doing that, there's no third ending, the Heart Room was already gold, and strictly nothing happens in it.

So, like [treyher](http://twitter.com/treyher/status/192738026974228480) says :

> Congratulations, searchers. It seems your quest is at an end (*monolith solved*), but the harder one begins now, and it begins with Where, and Why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So I decompiled FEZ.exe and found codes that only work when you're standing in the heart room beyond the 64 cube door...

You actually enter the codes in the *menu screen*—there's a separate code for both the letters and numbers artifacts. When you do both, the heart disintegrates, and the game does a faux-reboot!

The code to disintegrate the heart is (and BE WARNED: this worked fine on my Steam copy, but people are saying doing this on xbox actually corrupts their save—so beware, and maybe copy your save first if you're trying it there):

1. Get all the heart pieces, and go to the "Temple of Love" behind the 64 cube door.
2. Open the menu, go to the artifacts page.
3. Look at the red "letters" artifact and enter `LT RT RT LT RT LT LT LT`.
4. Look at the green "numbers" artifact and enter `RT RT RT LT RT RT LT LT`.

But I can't find anything else, past that. Nothing seems to change, and there's no extra ending. The heart room does remain empty though.

See [this GameFAQs post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/945079-fez/66110193) for details, or a [video of the heart disintegrating on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AUsGjZTSC-M).

Questions still remain...how were we supposed to figure these codes out? Were they "cut" from the game? Do the faces of the artifacts lead to them? What is the purpose of the alien skull artifact?

Comment: Could you perhaps add the code to your answer?

Comment: Sure. I added the important bits.

Comment: I meant the cheat code, not the C# code, lol

Comment: Oh, haha. Good point..

Comment: An anonymous [rejected edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/41644) claims while looking at the red "letters" artifact there's one `LT` missing at the end. Since they didn't provide further information, I assume it's a garbage edit, but just in case someone notices the answer doesn't work this might be the reason why... **edit** In fact looking at the code dump in [the previous revision](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/116092/2) suggest this might actually really be missing

Comment: Yes, "letters" code should end with 3x`LT`

Comment: Note: these codes to not work on the iPhone version of FEZ

Comment: Works on PS4 without corrupting the save. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It is highly probable that this particular puzzle was designed as a nudge to Kokoromi.

Kokoromi is an indie collective, Phil Fish used to work with them. Look at their logo :

[image]

As you said the heart room was already gold, I doubt there's anything more to it.

Comment: Do you have any actual information to support your answer?

Comment: This is just an easter egg, a wink to Kokoromi.

Comment: Looks like an input sequence (← A ← A RT A ↓ LT) to me.

Answer (score 2):

There's no additional ending because **the 64-cube ending was the final ending**. The heart cube piece trials were considered Easter eggs for adventurous gamers.

Also, the treyher quote is trolling. The game is partly about inventing explanations for things that cannot be explained, so while some connections between hidden rooms can be uncovered, there isn't always *something next*<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EWPi.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8t0W.png)</sup> (though the devs would prefer that you would think so).

[image: heart]

Comment: Do you have any actual information to support your answer?

Comment: I gave actual information. If you want support, there are only two endings: 32-cube, and 64-cube. Polytron's Twitter account [has stated](https://twitter.com/#!/Polytron/statuses/191192772332634112) that the alphabet cipher is not needed for the game, just Easter eggs. Since [the "What's my name" puzzle](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62421/21177) was the only one that required the alphabet cipher (for a heart cube piece), I concluded that the finished heart was an Easter egg hunt.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the game is done after that.
I think the whole game is about Eternalism
read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_%28philosophy_of_time%29)
and this story someone [posted](http://redvinesgiraffe.tumblr.com/post/40542619916/) on Tumblr also seemed to go along with this theory

Answer (score 0):

There is [discussion](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/961239-fez/62594884) going on regarding the discovery of images hidden in the soundtrack files.

The pictures that have been found so far are collated in that discussion. Examples can be seen [here](http://blackcoffeespirit.tumblr.com/post/21570402923).

This mystery may be the key to the *why* the code for the monolith was what it was (as hinted at in theyher's "WHERE and WHY" post) or it may be a new puzzle.