# What do the percentages mean in the overall leaderboards?

Tags: fez

I just stumbled upon the leaderboard and the xXRangerXx25, the current reigning champion has a percentage of 421.9%, followed by BeeMickSee 400% and smallest kiss 309.4%. What do all these percentages represent? How are they calculated?

Most people have 212.5%, which I assume is for fully complete the game, but 421.9? I don't get it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 32 cubes + 32 anticubes + 3 heart cube pieces @ 3.125% apiece => 209.4% max

- **32 cubes net 100%** for the first ending
- **64 cubes net 200%** for the second/final ending
- Three [heart cube pieces](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62803/21177) add **+9.4%** (optional, Easter eggs)
- Anything above that 209.4% is from a broken anticube.

<sub>**Source:** I'm `smallest kiss` (the first one above the max)</sub>

Comment: I know it's you, Sean :P. So it is a glitch? Did you repeatedly get the same anticube to get to where you are now? If yes, why? :)

Comment: Funny story: I found the same anticube respawning and thought I could just get it a bunch of times for the last achievement and move on with my life. It didn't work, so I collected the remaining anticubes. That didn't work, so I started a new game (speedrun). My leaderboards were [inaccessible](http://goo.gl/t7vba), so I didn't even know I had a ranking. Lots of Fez questions and forum activity popped up and I saw myself mentioned (much lulz), so I bypassed the leaderboard bug to see for myself. (BTW, the glitch is duplicable. A dev asked, and I offered him a bug report for the monolith code.)

Answer (score 3):

There is a [glitch that allows you to get one anti-cube repeatedly](http://www.giantbomb.com/fez/61-24768/400-completion-on-leaderboards-is-there-more-to-the-game/35-545133/?page=last).