# Where is my last anti-cube in FEZ?

Tags: fez

I bought FEZ when it first came out and played it fairly zealously for a short burst of time before becoming overwhelmed with work and other responsibilities.

I returned to it some time later, determined to not look anything up online unless I was absolutely stumped for two weeks or more.

I eventually got to 32 golden cubes and 27 anti-cubes.

I had not been able to figure out the alphabet yet, so finally reluctantly looked it up. It made sense in retrospect, but I have to say that I would never have figured it out on my own, unless I started a new save game (thus being able to remember which room I found the writing cube artifact in and being able to scour it for clues).

I translated as much text as I could find, so was able to read the security question in the candle room below the waterfall, which appears to be the only place where reading letters is necessary to acquire a collectible (apart from the Tome possibly being a clue to the monolith). Happily, the numbers had been much more straightforward.

I also looked up how to get the four-sided clock's last two anti-cubes.

I ended up using flying to reach the few treasure chests that you're meant to use the treasure maps to find hidden platforms to get to as well as the skull artifact, which was my last artifact acquired.

I have to admit that I finally just looked up the solution to the security question and the black monolith (sad day), however this brings me to...

**I have 32 gold cubes and 31 anti-cubes. I have (I believe) 3 heart pieces. 
The only two rooms that are not outlined in gold on my world map are:**

- **the *island with the 64-cube door*** (white outline plus 'Secret' icon) and
- ***the telescope observatory interior*** (white outline but no icon on the map) 
  I got both the heart piece and anti-cube in the observatory, ages ago. 
  What else is there in the observatory? I've stared at the patterns in the bookshelves below forever, but can't seem to make anything intelligible out of it.

I've also tried about every key combo that I could think of on the 64-cube door island to no avail.

**I'm at a loss as to where I'm meant to find the last anti-cube.
Any suggestions, friends?**

Comment: I used [this guide](http://www.xblafans.com/fez-cube-guide-observatory-area-45474.html) which is more or less complete.  If the area you're talking about is the room where the telescope is, have you done the shift cypher: Right, Shift Right, Left, Shift Right, Shift Right, Jump, Jump, Right in that room?

Comment: I think that the issue was that not long after starting the game my save file got corrupted and I had to start over again. Apparently the second time through, I got the heart piece but not the anti-cube.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the Giant Telescope room's secrets?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62492/what-are-the-giant-telescope-rooms-secrets)

Comment: Maybe you just forgot about the "Achievement unlocked" achievement :

RT RT LT RT RT LT LT LT

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Comment: I did not vote to close as off-topic but as dupe of [What are the Giant Telescope room's secrets?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62492/what-are-the-giant-telescope-rooms-secrets) Stupid majority rule...

Answer (score 2):

There are only [**two secrets** in the "giant telescope" observatory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62492/21177). Re-enter those codes and if they don't complete the room, the game is glitched. (You most likely need the room's anti-cube to finish your 64 collection.)