# What's the secret of the boiler/technician room in the beginning village?

Tags: fez

Do someone know what to do with this room ?

[image]

It's in the village from the beginning.

**Edit:** I found the solution alone, I didn't notice an hidden poster, during a perspective rotation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a code embedded in the posters on the wall.

[image: Boiler room]

Spoiler:

> The [numbered tetromino](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) posters around the room correspond to the code's order.

> E.g., above, #1 is <kbd>↑</kbd> and #5 is <kbd>→</kbd>.

The code is:

> **<kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>RT</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd> <kbd>LT</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>RT</kbd>**

Comment: I got 2 negative cubes out of this room .. I got frustrated and hit a random combination of buttons and got one .. the map still showed the room as white .. so i did the combo above and got the second one!

Comment: I just did it, and no, there is only 1 cube. (there is a map when you first walk in to pick up)

Comment: @NIMSS: There are some anti-cube codes that work in any room (such as the achievement one).

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What does 'up arrow RT...' etc mean?

Comment: @JonathanHartley: They're controller button sequences, like the Konami Code. If you're on PC, it would be the controller equivalent (A is jump, RT [right trigger] is rotate right).

Comment: @Sean: Thanks. I just discovered the QR code in the game that scans to read 'RT LT... etc' and through trial and error I discovered this translates into rotate right and left. Makes more sense to me now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks I missed the last sign, got to get used to the glasses :)

Comment: It is worth saying that from the 8 signs, the last one is hidden behind the boiler. And it can only be seen during the brief moment where the room is turning.

Comment: You can see the eighth sign also in first person view after your first play through

Comment: If you’re playing on Switch, “A” in this combo is “B” as that’s the jump button.