# How is the language code in Fez intended to be solved?

Tags: fez

A lot of text in Fez is encoded, including text from a number of NPCs. I'd assumed that you have to do something in-game to unlock the translation, but I haven't come across anything of the sort yet. Is there a Rosetta Stone-style resource in the game, or is the player actually intended to use cryptographic methods to solve the substitution?

Note that I'm not asking for a translation resource. I want to solve this puzzle myself, but I'd like to know if I actually should have been copying the tiny text from all those NPCs I encountered.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**There is one room in particular that provides what you're looking for.** You don't need to copy NPC dialog, though part of the fun is copying the other wall-writings for later consideration. So there is no single intended method (I imagine most people will [look online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/what-is-fezs-alphabet/62486#62486))—your method could work, though it sounds frustrating.

**Want a hint for that room's location?**

> It's off of the waterfall room.

**Want an even bigger hint?**

> A pillar in the room links the code to an English pangram (sentence containing every letter of the alphabet).

**And to give it away:**

> In the tree room above the waterfall, a fox jumps over a dog next to this pillar, which reads all the way around: ["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog) ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf22P.png))

Comment: I have actually read somewhere that somebody went through and used cryptography to figure it out. I can't imagine doing that myself... EDIT: I just read the answer under this, I have to respect determination like that.

Answer (score 11):

Eventually you get access to large amounts of text in the language code, which allowed me to work out the code using the normal approach you'd use for a substitution cipher -- spot frequently used symbols and repeated patterns, guess at the vowels and common words,build from there.

Later, I found a "rosetta stone" in the form of a pangram written alongside the thing it described.