# How is the number / tetris code in Fez intended to be solved?

Tags: fez

In the same spirit as : [How is the language code in Fez intended to be solved?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62575/how-is-the-language-code-in-fez-intended-to-be-solved)

I was able to crack the language code using tradition substitution cipher breaking techniques.

But I ended up cheating on the number/tetris symbols by looking on the Internet.

The number code is logical enough now I know it -- but I can't see how I would have arrived at it without help.

With regard to tetris shapes:

> What would cause you to go down the path of associating Tetris shapes with controller inputs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Tetromino/Tetris block cipher

Controller inputs are only associated with tetrominos **once**.

**Where?**

> Towards the top of the map, in the tree [near the octopus building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlOyh.png) that houses the solar system model.

**What's inside?**

> A puzzle that displays tetromino blocks based off of controller inputs, and an anticube prize for cracking the nearby pillar's code. ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb0No.png)) ([link to finished cipher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177))

The **classroom in the 8-cube *Blade Runner* city** then shows how to interpret the pillars with tetromino inscriptions. Here's one wall, but relate it to the others:

[image: tetromino pillar]

### Numbers cipher

Like the alphabet, there isn't one proper way to do this, but you might be interested in the 16-cube temple's classroom. Instead of trekking back, this is what it looks like:

[image: 16-cube temple's classroom #1]
[image: 16-cube temple's classroom #2]
[image: 16-cube temple's classroom #3]

**Hint:**

> Those are "equals" signs, and the last picture is arithmetic. Also, the figure/ground is confusing—pay attention to the box and its internal vertical/horizontal lines, not the "C" shapes. ([link to finished cipher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177))

Comment: Also, there are more "three-number-sums-that-equals-to-ten" drawings at the sides of the library where the planets are rotating. So, there you go, even more hints. (but I confess I couldn't figure it out by myself)

Comment: Do the 1-pixel-wide vertical lines carry any meaning?

Answer (score 2):

For the tetris shapes:

> There is a room where a pillar flashes the appropriate shape when you apply the input near it. There's a tetris-shaped chain next to it to test the inputs on. It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfnDd.png

It was really satisfying to figure that one out for myself, I loved that puzzle.

For the numbers:

> The numbers are in order on a wall (in the big-head village I think), and 1-4 are on connected treasure maps.

Comment: Blast, I feel like such a quitter now. Should've trusted the designer to be fair. And the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the tetris blocks translations there's also a schoolroom with the explanation marked down on a blackboard on how to view them.