# What do the "numbers" wall inscriptions in the 16-cube temple classroom mean or represent?

Tags: fez

You know that room ?

[image: 1]

What does this mean?

[image: 2]

I can translate the numbers, but it doesn't make any sense... Could it be words ?

Then, I was also wondering if those symbols below the numbers 0 1 2 3 here does mean anything :

[image: 3]

Answer (score 4):

[image: unfolded cube]

**This is the unfolded counting cube.** The numbers don't mean anything by themselves, but the cube is meant to *associate* these types of symbols (portions of a plus sign) with numbers. Seeing the unfolded cube in this 16-cube classroom informs us that this room is about numbers, since it uses the same symbols. Some deduction in this room leads to [solving the number cipher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62812/21177).

[image: dimensions]

**This is [the number cipher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) giveaway.** These symbols are used in various rooms, but they form a ***[Flatland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland)* sequence** here. (*Flatland*'s conceit is not understanding other dimensions until you can personally experience them.) Without blowing the story, a square protagonist lives in a two-dimensional world, visits Lineland (a one-dimensional world), and later, Spaceland (3-D) and Pointland (0-D). Knowing this, the sequence is fairly straightforward: the numbers represent the dimensions from zero to three.

[image: equals]

Likewise, these show three ways of adding to 10, introduce an "equals" sign, show that "three" can be written two different ways, and that a godly squid bequeathed the gift of 3-D.

[image: 64]

**I don't think this means anything, nor does anyone else.** The numbers add up to 64, a prescient number in this game, and when adding the numbers separated by spaces and converting them to letters via a substitution cipher, they spell a naughty word. **This game is steeped in [apophenia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia), looking for patterns in static—we don't know if we're being trolled by the game designers.**

Comment: "I don't think this means anything, nor does anyone else." Anyone else except Phil Fish that is...
see: https://twitter.com/soundofjw/status/350292588198240257

Comment: How are you supposed to figure out the symbol for 10?

Comment: @thejoshwolfe: I think it'll make sense if you read the whole thing through, but I show how you can figure out the number system first and then use the equal sign markings to add multiple numbers together.

Comment: @Sean: Sorry, I've read your post several times; I still don't get where 10 comes from. Is there a pattern to unlock all the numbers at once? It seems like we just get a symbol here and there, and the only way to know is to learn about each symbol individually.

Comment: @thejoshwolfe: In the left part of the third image, three symbols each add up to one symbol (which looks like a plus sign or four dots depending on how you look at it). I'm about to spoil the number cipher, so if you don't want that, go [here first](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62763/21177). ... Okay, so think of the symbols for 1, 2, 3, and 4 all representing a line coming from one of the four sides, so if you were to add all four of those lines into one composite image, you'd get "10". Eh?

Comment: @Sean: that's kinda cool, but it's not consistent. It works for 1+2=3, and 1+2+3+4=10, but not 1+3=4, or 2+5=7. I see now that it actually works for a lot of them, but it doesn't always work. So perhaps that is the trick I was supposed to catch on to, but it's frustrating how fuzzy it is. I guess my expectations for consistency were too high.

Comment: @thejoshwolfe: There is no "5" so that equation wouldn't work. "1+3=4" would be a straight vertical line, as you can see used in the third image. It works for all of them.

Comment: @Sean: Although I don't like your explanation, I think you're on the right track. I wrote up a "complete" explanation, which took 2 days, 30 images, and ~30 paragraphs of text. I link to it in this question/answer: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168459/how-is-the-fez-number-cipher-intended-to-be-solved

Comment: What is the naughty word? Going up-down/right-left, I got `4,5; 6,1,4,4,3,6; 2,2,3; 4,5,4,3,3,5`. Added together, these yield `9, 24, 7, 24`, following the substitution cipher direction, (`a=1, b=2, ...`), I got "IXGX". I then rotated that around all 26 ways (ROT 0..25) and the closest two words resembling English were "PENE" and "CRAR" (ROT 7 and 20, respectively)

Comment: @BradenBest PENE means penis in Italian, if that's the "naughty word" you are looking for. I was wandering the same, btw.

Answer (score 2):

For people who didn't use a guide this room holds a major clue to decipher the numbers.

The last image (that says 0 1 2 3) shows you the glyphs for 0, 1, 2 and one of the options for 3 (i.e. 1+2).

I'm not sure of the purpose of the others, but they are:

Vertical numbers:

```
2 4
2 5
3
  6
4 1
5 4
4 4
3 3 
3 6
5
```

Cube net:

```
   10
1  4  6  5
      0

1 4 6 5 10 0
```

I don't think the first one is significant, but the second is a net of the number cube artefact. With those 6 shapes (in various orientations) you can express every number in the system.

Answer (score 0):

It says,"

1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10

1+2+7=10

2+3+5=10

1+4+5=10"

Comment: Do you have any sources to back this up?

Comment: I don't even know what that means.