# How is the Fez number cipher intended to be solved?

Tags: fez

Every walkthrough/guide/faq I've found for FEZ just has the answer to the number cipher, but not the steps you're supposed to take to solve it on your own. How is it intended to be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an essay (with pictures!) explaining how I think the number cipher is intended to be solved.

[How you should have solved the Fez number cipher](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JKaha6Vq7T3vSpOXbqlco-U3Q1Wu6pXQPjLvwTBjbjE/pub)

Here's the cliff notes:

1. Figure out 0-3 from the dimension diagram.
2. Figure out the set of symbols for 1-8 from the boiler room, although you don't know which ones are which.
3. See that 3 is not in the boiler room symbols, which means there must be multiple symbols for 3.
4. See the formulas in the classroom, and guess what the two horizontal lines mean.
5. Notice that overlaying images corresponds to adding numbers.
6. Figure out all the numbers, most importantly the all the single-limbs numbers.

And then you know everything. But steps 3-6 kinda have to be done on faith that you're on the right track, because you get no confirmation until the end. That makes this a really hard puzzle.

Comment: Not sure what the boiler room has to do with it. Thought my explanation was straightforward

Comment: @Sean: I suppose I'm looking for a much more pedantic walkthrough for each step of the reasoning. Figuring out the big points like the non-bijectivity and the adding notation aren't immediately obvious. Furthermore, guessing them doesn't get any confirmation until many steps later.