# Is there any 'Best' path in FEZ?

Tags: fez

I'm wondering if there could be a path that is considered the 'best', in terms of speed of completion and overall understanding of the 'multiverse' area, like ciphers and its layout. Should one go to the ciphers first (and how to get to them from the nearest warp gates), or should I follow all the paths that lead to small gates first (these could be called 'side paths', if you like)?

Basically what I'm asking is, would I be missing a lot if I don't know the codes when I first encounter them, or would it be better to have the experience of having to find them?

Comment: Sorry, is this considered subjective? I'll remove it if enough people say it is, I posted this before I spent the time to check over it, and it's my first one so I don't really know the procedure very well in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fez is really about exploration and fun puzzles. I myself haven't beaten it, but the way I figure it is that you basically go where you want to go and do what you want to do. As you mentioned in your own comment, I think it is subjective. It is possible that there are some people that do speed runs and have it down to an art, but beyond that I think you should just enjoy it to your heart's content :)

Comment: Alright, thank you. I was just wondering if there was like a popular course, but I do think that free-roaming is the best path I ould choose.

Answer (score 2):

The game is designed to be explored the first time and to be solved the second time. There is nothing "missable" in the game and there's no rush to solve any one room. It's supposed to be a "stop and smell the flowers" kind of game, and the game only requires half the cubes (32 of 64) for the ending so that you can return with extra powers in the New Game+ to make the puzzle-solving more interesting and less tedious. Keep in mind that not a single one of the early reviewers wrote about successfully figuring out Fez's alphabet.

Since you asked for general strategy, I recommend going as deep down each branch as possible the first time. If you open doors and quickly return without following their paths, you'll likely confuse yourself when you return to the map and try to figure out what each node was supposed to represent when you were barely in the room. As for entering doors that need ciphers the first time around, the game was designed for a degree of [apophenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia): you look at things and not know how you're supposed to approach them. Experience says that you'll enjoy the game more if you only rely on Arqade once you're completely stuck. And then [ask *how*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62575/21177) you can figure out the alphabet, not for the cipher directly.

Answer (score 0):

Still working on my way through Fez, currently at ~40%. But there seem to be some [speed run](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suQb72CiSVc) videos out there. I gather that you can complete the game without doing everything or solving everything. However, I agree with Link of Origin that this game is more about the exploring and puzzle solving. The unlimited lives and retries also make this game so much more relaxed and enjoyable.