# What's the secret in the infinite purple room?

Tags: fez

There's a secret I've had trouble finding in the purple infinite room with a waterfall :

[image: Infinite room on the map]

I've tried looking in first person on every floor and wall but haven't found any instruction.

Could someone give us a hint, or an answer in spoiler tags?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Hint: Tilt your head the right.**

**Another hint:**

> The structure itself is a [tetromino code](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177). Decode and enter it for an anticube.

**Answer:**

> Press **→ LT → A RT ↓ A ↑**. An anticube will appear.

Answer (score 3):

Break it down:

> The shapes of the platforms are joined Tetris shapes that signify a bunch of button presses.

Comment: -1, because @sean's answer follows the OP's request of keeping the answer in spoiler tags, while your answer is just spoiler.

Comment: My answer above was my first and only post on this stackexchange. I wasn't aware there was a spoiler tag. Now I am, so I've changed it. Next time, maybe just jump right in and edit rather than spreading negativity.

Comment: @Matt Some of us will just jump in and edit.  Some of us will try to point you in the right direction as to how to go about changing things.  Teach a man to fish and all that.

Comment: @Frank If you are going to take that approach that requires you to have the ability to follow through and retract the downvote after the post has been edited, which the downvoter clearly has forgotten to do.