# How do you lower the water in the lighthouse area and main warp room?

Tags: fez

I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas or if they knew how to lower the water in those areas, I know you can and I know you have to. I just don't know how. Soooo yeah, if anyone can help me, then thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the waterfall room, [enter the tetromino code](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) on the pillar to open a door beneath the waterfall. The valve in this room lowers the water across the first warp zone. This is unrelated to [the moon door](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62888/21177).

**Solution:**

> Enter this [code](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) anywhere in the room: **← LT → RT ↑ A ↓ RT RT**.

[image: Waterfall hidden room]

Comment: Yeah.... so how do you do this on PC? Buy a XBox controller?

Comment: @Kenny: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/150364/21177

Answer (score 2):

The secret to lowering the water in that whole area (main warp room, lighthouse, windmill, waterfall, lonely-tree island) lies in the weeping/puking waterfall area. The huge column in that area is what you should be paying attention to.

If you've played the game a lot you'd notice similar columns with similar codes inscribed onto them.

edit: [What is Fez's alphabet?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/what-is-fezs-alphabet)
that might help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear the 'Well' area?

On the map, default position, starting from the green warp zone, you have to go bottom right, then top right.

I'm not 100% sure but this area involve puzzle revolving around water levels.

Comment: Yea I've been there but there was 1 door I couldn't open because I can't find another key anywhere. So yeah, I appreciate the help though.