# How to solve the tree island puzzle off of the bell tower node?

Tags: fez

The node directly off the bell tower is giving me trouble. It's a tree on a pyramid surrounded by water with a hole on one side that makes i noise but i dont know what to do. If anyone knows it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **[lower the water](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62659/how-do-you-lower-the-water-in-the-lighthouse-area-and-main-warp-room)**. The sound you hear is a door submerged underwater.

Where does the door lead?

> It's a 64-cube door. It reveals a room with a floating heart. It fills with three red cube pieces. This room is considered an Easter egg.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to worry about that until later, but it does involve the area in the waterfall. But that is all I will say.