# Some tetromino codes aren't registering

Tags: fez

In the waterfall room, I've been trying to enter both the sequence on the pillar and on the golden door, and neither seems to be working. For instance, my translation of the pillar is (RT = right turn):

RT RT up jump down RT left LT right

I've tried this multiple times, all over the level, and using the D-pad in case I was being sloppy with the joystick; nothing happens. Is something wrong with my translation, or do I need to do something more than just press these buttons in sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any tetromino code in the game, you only need to input the button sequence to see the effect occur. If the pillar you are looking at is the one in the picture below, you seem to have translated the pillar incorrectly.

[image: pillar picture]
(borrowed from [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62682/1787))

The actual sequence is

> left LT right RT up A down RT RT

To get these sequences, you have to rotate your head 90 degrees to the right before reading the symbols from to to bottom.

Comment: Completely wrong may be a little strong :).  I think he just read from the bottom instead of reading from the top.  In general as you go through the game, the writing should all be interpreted top to bottom.

Comment: @EBongo You're probably right. I only noticed that the code given was completely different from the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

**You're doing fine**—you just read the code in the opposite direction.

Check out my tetromino-reading tutorial [on this page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177).