# What are the FEZ tetris codes for the PC?

Tags: fez

Everywhere I search, I can't find the tetris codes for the PC. Could someone help me on this?

I already know the directions, and I'm assuming left and right trigger are the equivalents of A and D, and I think A on XBOX is the ctrl equivalent, except this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard has been remappable [since v1.08](https://getsatisfaction.com/polytron/topics/keyboard_mapping) and the tetrominos [map](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) to functions (up/down/left/right/jump/rotate left/rotate right), so the "codes" will change based on your setup.

By default, <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> are mapped to rotate left/right (respectively), the arrow keys are for movement, and <kbd>Space</kbd> by default.

Comment: For more, see the "Controls" section of [this Steam page](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=144370815)