# How in Fez do you lower the water on the bell side island with the tree and underneath a pyramid?

Tags: xbox-360, fez

How do you lower the water on the bell side island with the tree and underneath a pyramid?

This is the tree with pyramid.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the 64 cube pyramid, to lower the water you need to go to the crying face waterfall and enter the tetromino code.

[How do you lower the water in the lighthouse area and main warp room?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62659/how-do-you-lower-the-water-in-the-lighthouse-area-and-main-warp-room)