# King thrones puzzle?

Tags: fez

I noticed that there are two rooms in the game with a king's throne. One of them is nice and shiny and the other one is old. Easy of them has a code in front of the seat that you can see only when you use the 3D view (game+).

First room location on the map:
[image: First room location on the map.]

Second room location on the map:
[image: Second room location on the map.]

Any ideas where to use these codes? I tried using them in the rooms I found them in (also vice versa), but nothing happened.

(system won't let me to post more than two links, I will add more images once I can post them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the throne room codes *can* be **combined to solve the sewer's QR puzzle without a QR reader**, but it's really convoluted:

[image: throne codes]

Stack the 16-cube door temple's code ("newer throne") above the temple warp zone's code ("dilapidated throne"). Then [read the code](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) vertically from left to right: RRLRRRLLRLLLRLRL.

If you solve the QR puzzles normally, the throne rooms will turn gold ("completed") on their own.

Answer (score 4):

You have to combine the two codes.

Nice Throne :

> RT LT RT LT RT LT RT RT

Old Throne :

> RT RT RT LT LT LT LT LT

Solution :

> RT RT LT RT RT RT LT LT RT LT LT LT RT LT RT LT

Comment: I entered this in the second throne room.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are alternate puzzles for players who cannot do the QR code scans. If you've already gotten a cube by inputting the combo from a QR code, the throne rooms will do nothing and should turn gold eventually.

Comment: That must be it, I used the QR codes.