# What does the sewer QR code return?

Tags: fez

Okay this is bothering the crap out of me. Pictured is a photo of a QR code only displayed on the map of a room in the sewer area right off the main warp gate. I didn't notice it until after I "golded" the area (which I think was just a stupid cube bit). Anyways, my QR reader on my phone won't read it. I can only assume it is due to the sheen effect since I cleared the area.

[image: The QR code]

What does this QR code say?

Comment: You say that you made the room gold. Is the QR code still there? Also, what do you want to know?

Comment: Yes its only shown on the map. (struggling with adding imgs atm)

Comment: Then I assume you are asking what the code said?

Answer (score 5):

If you completed/"golded" the room already, you don't need to enter the QR code. You're done. If you did [the throne puzzle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62802/21177), the sewer QR room will complete automatically. If you're curious, the QR code just returns this text: `RT RT LT RT RT RT LT LT RT LT LT LT RT LT RT LT`

[image: sewer QR room]

This is what a screenshot of what the iPhone QR reader returns:

[image: QR response]

Comment: Thanks. Was thinking it was a hidden secret like the stars blinking in the telescope room.

Comment: What's the name of your QR Code Reader App?...

Comment: Isn't that a code to enter alternating `Right Trigger` and `Left Trigger` ?

Comment: @Gimlao: I downloaded [whatever was the top-rated QR reader](http://appshopper.com/utilities/qr-reader-for-iphone)

Comment: @Eregrith:: Yes

Comment: Entering in the Right-Left code listed in the other answer on this questions nets you an anticube