# What is the secret to the classroom in the 8-cube door city in Fez?

Tags: fez

The room is located in the 8-cube door city-esque place. It has 3 walls with chalkboards on them and one with a blue/green picture of what looks like it might be a map of the world. I can't figure out the puzzle any help?

Answer (score 14):

**You have to use [the tetromino cipher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62486/21177) on the chalkboard.**

[image: chalkboard]

**The answer:**

> or just press: **↑ ← RT A LT → A ↓**, and an anticube will appear

Answer (score 4):

The main blackboard (shown in [Sean's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62826/106901)) either teaches you about the tetris codes or it drops a hint about how the numbers work.

The same sequence is shown 3 times, each with a number next to it.

**1** - the code as it appears on pillars (in that form on another wall)

**2** - the code split out into its constituent tetris pieces

**3** (shown as 1+2) - the code turned on its side how you should input it.

Another room teaches you how to input that code.

These three steps show you how to read the input code every time you see one of those vertical glyphs.

Answer (score 4):

For keyboard:
Up arrow, Left arrow, D, Space, A, Right arrow, Space, Down arrow

Answer (score 3):

It's the code sequence on the wall. Each tetrimino (Tetris piece) corresponds to a different button on your gamepad. The answer to this specific one is Up, Left, Right trigger, A, Left trigger, Right, A, Down.

Answer (score -2):

## World Map

map of the world is go to the snow, bottom. press rt a a lt lt b b a rt and ut gives you a cube.
psvita r x x l l o o r

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. That is not an appropriate use of the Low Quality flags. Low qualty is intended for junk answers which can't be salvaged, such as "asdasdasd". It is not meant for answers which are unclear, and don't present the information in a poor manner. **Downvote** these answers, do not flag them.