# How do I replace the cryptic alphabet font in Fez, so I can read the text?

Tags: pc, fez

I quickly discovered that the gibberish written all over the place is a [mono-alphabetic cipher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/what-is-fezs-alphabet).  It was easy to crack, but, I'd rather not have to do the replacements by hand *(or google that particular translation)* every time I want to read something.

Now that the game is out for PC, is there some way to replace the font-files in game so these show up in English?

Comment: Fez is based on XNA, so there should be a way to swap the original texture with the one with comprehensible characters. The resource files are packed in some kind of archive (I presume they're just serialized, hence the dll). One way to do this is to make a wrapper game application using a reflection, it all boils down to finding the correct texture to swap.

Comment: not a direct solution, but there are apps for smartphones that can help you translate the texts. I've used [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.injection18.fezdecoder&feature=search_result) for android You still need to enter each "character" but it's something! It would be nice if they made an app that can "read" the text from pictures or something.

Answer (score 2):

Fez's source code has been decompiled (and can easily be done), so it is entirely possible to do this.  It, however, has not been done already.  Do you want to do it? ;)

You should note, however, that this would only fix the chat with the hexahedron, zu villagers, etc.  It would NOT fix the artifacts (including the tome I believe), and any clues thrown about the environment (engraved into walls, etc.) because these are predefined art assets.  One would need to edit all of these assets individually in order to translate them.

#### Cipher for the alphabet:

> [image: FEZ cipher for the alphabet]

#### Cipher for the numbers:

> [image: FEZ cipher for the numbers]